# DALI specification: help to understand the physical layer schematic

Tags: opto-isolator, dali

I am trying to understand an NXP circuit that has implemented the physical layer of the DALI specification. In particular, it is [DALI master hardware](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/AN11175.pdf).  For the transmission (page 4), it says exactly:

> For high signals of DALI1_TX, Optocoupler OK2 connects junction R2 and R3 to the DALI bus, which creates a drive current for the base of T1 that starts to conduct and short circuit the DALI bus via bridge B1.

But I understand just the opposite: when DALI1_TX is a high (3.3 V), the direct current through the optocoupler diode is zero and therefore, the optocoupler transistor is cut-off. Then, the base current of 'T1' is zero and the transistor is cut-off. What am I doing wrong?

The explanation for the reception (page 5) I do not understand correctly either. When the bus is idle, the 'OK2' optocoupler transistor is saturated and therefore, DALI1_RX is a low level. On the other hand, when there is a low level in the bus, the optocoupler transistor does not drive and DALI_RX is a high level. It is right?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the terminology is sort of messed up.

They refer to `1` bit as `high signal`.

They are not referring to the voltage on the wire.

The DALI1_TX and DALI1_RX are `active low`.

The signals are pulled low by an open collector output for a `1` bit and left floating for a `0` bit (pulled to 3.3V by the pullup resistor).

So the `high signal` is actually 0V on the wire.